# How to validate a user chose at least one checkbox in a CheckBoxList?

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation, checkbox, checkboxlist

I've got a CheckBoxList control that I want to require the user to check at least ONE box, it does not matter if they check every single one, or 3, or even just one.

In the spirit of asp.net's validation controls, what can I use to enforce this? I'm also using the Ajax validation extender, so it would be nice if it could look like other controls, and not some cheesy server validate method in the codebehind.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns="3" ID="ckBoxListReasons" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Preliminary Construction" Value="prelim_construction" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Final Construction" Value="final_construction" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Construction Alteration" Value="construction_alteration" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Remodel" Value="remodel" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Color" Value="color" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Brick" Value="brick" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Exterior Lighting" Value="exterior_lighting" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Deck/Patio/Flatwork" Value="deck_patio_flatwork" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Fence/Screening" Value="fence_screening" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Landscape - Front" Value="landscape_front" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Landscape - Side/Rear" Value="landscape_side_rear" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="other" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery? If yes, it will be very simple. Give all your checkboxes a class name say 'reasons'. $('.reasons :checked').length == 0 means that user didn't select any checkbox and you can display an error.

Comment: I want to just use the validators built into .NET.... I'm not really going to be able to use jQuery.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's easy to do this validation server side, but I am assuming you want to do it client side?

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/) can do this very easily as long as you have something that all checkbox controls have in common to use as a selector such as class (CssClass on your .NET control).  You can make a simple [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) function and connect it to a ASP.NET custom validator.  Remember if you do go the custom validator route to make sure you check it server side as well in case javascript is not working, you don't get a free server side check like the other .NET validators.

For more information on custom validators check out the following links: [www.asp.net](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/validation/default.aspx) and
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx.aspx)

You don't need to use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), it just makes the javascript function to iterate and look at all your checkbox controls much easier but you can just use vanilla javascript if you like.

Here is an example I found at: [Link to original](http://pankajlalwani.blogspot.com/2009/05/validating-checkboxlist-using.html)

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkModuleList"runat="server" >
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvmodulelist"
  ClientValidationFunction="ValidateModuleList"
  ErrorMessage="Please Select Atleast one Module" ></asp:CustomValidator>

// javascript to add to your aspx page
function ValidateModuleList(source, args)
{
  var chkListModules= document.getElementById ('<%= chkModuleList.ClientID %>');
  var chkListinputs = chkListModules.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i=0;i<chkListinputs .length;i++)
  {
    if (chkListinputs [i].checked)
    {
      args.IsValid = true;
      return;
    }
  }
  args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Side Note: [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) is just a little js file include you need to add to your page.  Once you have it included you can use all the [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) you like.  Nothing to install and it will be full supported in the next version of Visual Studio I think.

Comment: Is there anyway to generalizing this? How do I modify the javascript function to have it take the "ControlToValidate" in CustomValidator; instead of hard-coding "<%= chkModuleList.ClientID %>" ?

Comment: It's confusing that OP said in a comment "I can't really use jQuery" and *then* this answer is posted assuming the opposite, and even more confusing is that OP accepted it. Especially if it's "easy" to do the validation server-side (e.g. using C#), I wonder why this answer doesn't just show how to do it on the server side.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a cleaner **jQuery** implementation that allows one **ClientValidationFunction** for any number of **CheckBoxList** controls on a page:

```
function ValidateCheckBoxList(sender, args) {
    args.IsValid = false;

    $("#" + sender.id).parent().find("table[id$="+sender.ControlId+"]").find(":checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        args.IsValid = true;
        return;
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the markup:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server"
          Id="cblOptions" 
          DataTextField="Text" 
          DataValueField="Id" />

<xx:CustomValidator Display="Dynamic" 
              runat="server" 
              ID="cblOptionsValidator"
              ControlId="cblOptions"
              ClientValidationFunction="ValidateCheckBoxList" 
              ErrorMessage="One selection required." />
```

And finally, the custom validator that allows the client function to retrieve the target control by ID:

```
public class CustomValidator : System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator
{
    public string ControlId { get; set; }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Enabled)
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(ClientID, "ControlId", ControlId);

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why but when the CheckBoxList is inside Update Panel and a partial post back is made.. It gives error even when the selection was made prior to partial post back.. It's the JQuery problem, the JavaScript solution accepted as answer works in this case..

Comment: +1 neat solution. I had trouble with accepted answer when `CheckBoxList` is in a `FormView`. @ArsalanAdamKhatri To get this working with `UpdatePanel`, replace `Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(ClientID, "ControlId", ControlId);` with `ScriptManager.RegisterExpandoAttribute(this, ClientID, "ControlId", ControlId, true);`

Comment: I was confused you couldn't use sender.controltovalidate. Turns out you get: `Control 'x' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'valX' cannot be validated.` if you try - even though _you're writing the validation function yourself_ - so _of course_ it _can_ be validated!

Comment: It is worth noting that this answer does NOT WORK with RepeatLayout="UnorderedList" - unlike the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CustomValidator` for that with a little bit of javascript.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Select at least one"
    ClientValidationFunction="checkCheckBoxList"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkCheckBoxList(oSrc, args) {
        var isValid = false;
        $("#<%= CheckBoxList1.ClientID %> input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function (i, obj) {
            isValid = true;
        });
        args.IsValid = isValid;
    }
</script>
```

And for a `RadioButtonList`

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Select at least one" ClientValidationFunction="checkRadioButtonList"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkRadioButtonList(oSrc, args) {
        if ($("input[name='<%= RadioButtonList1.UniqueID %>']:checked").val() == null) {
            args.IsValid = false;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that may be considered via [Dado.Validators](https://github.com/roydukkey/Dado.Validators) on GitHub.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCheckBoxList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box (empty)" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box 1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box 2" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box 3" Value="3" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<Dado:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="cblCheckBoxList" ValidationGroup="vlgSubmit" />
```

Example codebehind.aspx.cs

```
btnSubmit.Click += (a, b) =>
{
    Page.Validate("vlgSubmit");
    if (Page.IsValid) {
        // Validation Successful
    }
};
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dado.Validators/

Ref: [Check if a checkbox is checked in a group of checkboxes in clientside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529319/check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-a-group-of-checkboxes-in-clientside/18276684#18276684)

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by C# also

```
 bool Item_selected = false;
        foreach (ListItem item in checkbox.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected == true)
            {
                Item_selected = true;
            }
        }
        if (!Item_selected )
        {
          //your message to user
          //  message = "Please select atleast one checkbox";
          
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop through each of the items in ckBoxListReasons. Each item will be of type 'ListItem'.

The ListItem will have a property called 'Selected' that is a boolean. It's true when that item is selected. Something like:

```
Dim bolSelectionMade As Boolean = False
For Each item As ListItem in ckBoxListReasons.Items
 If item.Selected = True Then
  bolSelectionMade = True
 End If
Next
```

*bolSelectionMade* will be set to true if the user has made at least one selection. You can then use that to set the Valid state of any particular validator control you like.

Comment: Or a more compact form in C# would be: args.IsValid = ckBoxListReasons.Items.Any(item => item.Selected);

Comment: You can't use .Any() because the Items collection is not descended from IEnumerable<T> - it's ListItemCollection.

Comment: You can use ckBoxListReasons.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(item => item.Selected);