# requiredfieldvalidator on a checkbox created programatically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, validation, checkbox, requiredfieldvalidator

this is part of code for my checkbox.

```
 For Each c As Contact In contacts.Entries
            counter += 1
            tr = New HtmlTableRow
            tc = New HtmlTableCell

            Dim chkbox As New CheckBox
            chkbox.ID = "id_" & counter
            tc.Controls.Add(chkbox)
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
```

Next

now this will create 1 to n, checkboxes depending on the records pulled form DB. On the user side, i need them to check minimum one checkbox before clicking submit. howcan i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx). Then you can validate on server- or clientside if the user checked at least one.
Have a look at this answer: [stackoverflow: asp-net-checkboxgroup-validate-user-chooses-at-least-one-checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146234/asp-net-checkboxgroup-validate-user-chooses-at-least-one-checkbox)