# Check if a checkbox is checked in a group of checkboxes in clientside

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Please note that the scenario is ASP.NET Webforms + Master - Content page which mess up the ids.
I have, say, three checkboxes

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkConsultantQuality" runat="server" 
            CssClass="company"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkConsultantEnvironment" runat="server" 
            CssClass="company"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkConsultantSafety" runat="server" 
            CssClass="company"/>
```

I would like to make a `div id="CompanyPanel"` on click event of each checkbox according to the following condition

1. visible if any of the checkboxes are  checked.
2. hidden if all of the checkboxes are unchecked.

I am planning to use jQuery since I am selecting by class name. I could do it with `jQuery.each` on the class='company' by checking each for a checked flag.
Any better ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `:checked` ( http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ ) selector you can use :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".company input").click(function() {
            var cnt = $(".company input:checked").length;

            if( cnt == 0)
            {
               // none checked
               $('#CompanyPanel').hide();
            }
            else
            {
               // any checked
               $('#CompanyPanel').show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**You may want to add (or use) an id on the container of these checkbox, to optimize selector speed.**

As for asp.net messing up client ids on controls, you can use

```
$('<% =MyControl.ClientID %>')
```

Comment: +1: thanks. well, should the selector be ".company input:checkbox:checked" since asp:CheckBox wraps the input around a span?

Answer (score 5):

You can just wait for the `click` event on all checkboxes, and perform your validation there. No need for `.each()`. This way, you validate whenever any of the checkboxes have been checked or unchecked.

```
$('input.company:checkbox').click(function(){
    if ($('input.company:checkbox:checked').length > 0)
    {
        $('div#CompanyPanel').show();
    }
    else 
    {
        $('div#CompanyPanel').hide();
    }
});
```

You can just optimize it a bit as well, and change according to your needs.

Comment: +1: thanks. well, should the selector be `".company input:checkbox:checked"` since asp:CheckBox wraps the input around a span?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where ASP.NET slaps that CssClass on --- if it does go on the `SPAN` then yeah, good catch. :D +1

Comment: sorry i couldn't mark both as answers.mathieu was a tad faster.

Comment: don't worry about it --- the point of SO is to get your correct answer, not who actually gives you the correct answer. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this very easily with a CheckBoxList and a [Dado.Validators](https://github.com/roydukkey/Dado.Validators) which provides support for CheckBoxLists. Note this provides client-side and server-side validation.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCheckBoxList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box (empty)" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box 1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box 2" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box 3" Value="3" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<Dado:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="cblCheckBoxList" ValidationGroup="vlgSubmit" />
```

Example codebehind.aspx.cs

```
btnSubmit.Click += (a, b) =>
{
    Page.Validate("vlgSubmit");
    if (Page.IsValid) {
        // Validation Successful
    }
};
```

There are many other useful feature in Dado.Validators worth a look-see.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dado.Validators/