# Javascript or JQuery for ASP.NET RadioButtonGroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I just need to get the selected index from my radiobuttongroup on the client side. However, I'm really new to Javascript/JQuery, and came across some behavior that seemed really odd. I have a dropdownlist and a radiobuttongroup in the same table.  In my script, I have the following:

```
var ddlStatuses = $find("<%= ddlStatuses.ClientID %>");
var rbgAssetClass = $find("<%= rbgAssetClass.ClientID %>");
```

The first $find works as I would expect, but the second is returning null.

So two questions. What's the best way to find my radiobuttongroup and get its selected index, and why is $find finding one of these controls but not the other when they're in the same table?

Thanks

Edited to show aspx:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSelectRoom" CssClass="pnlSelectRoom" runat="server" Width="930px">
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" class="tblSelectRoomLayout" Width="100%">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Data Center" Font-Size="Small" </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:DropDownList Width="225px" ID="ddlDataCenter" runat="server" onchange="PopulateRooms(this);"
                        ZIndex="9001" Font-Size="Small" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Room" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:DropDownList Width="225px" ID="ddlRooms" runat="server"  ZIndex="9001" Enabled ="false">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Asset Status"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox Width="225px" runat="server" ID="ddlStatuses" DataValueField="ID"
                        DataTextField="Text" CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="True" ZIndex="9001" CausesValidation="false">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>                        
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow Width="100%">
                <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="6" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="checkBoxAlign" ID="rbgAssetClass" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"
                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                        Font-Size="Small">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Base Assets&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Contained Assets&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SubContained Assets</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>All Assets&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Could you post the asp code with the readio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below.

**It does not matter in JavaScript that where control are either or content page or master page**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkModuleList"runat="server" />

<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvmodulelist"
  ClientValidationFunction="ValidateModuleList"
  ErrorMessage="Please Select Atleast one Module" />

// javascript to add to your aspx page
function ValidateModuleList(source, args)
{
  var chkListModules= document.getElementById ('<%= chkModuleList.ClientID %>');
  var chkListinputs = chkListModules.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i=0;i<chkListinputs .length;i++)
  {
    if (chkListinputs [i].checked)
    {
      args.IsValid = true;
      return;
    }
  }
  args.IsValid = false;
}
```

**Update:**
Or you can go through this approach: Put any `css-class` say `company`. You can go through below.

There is a `:checked` ( http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ ) selector you can use :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".company input").click(function() {
            var cnt = $(".company input:checked").length;
            if (cnt == 0)
            {
               // none checked
            }
            else
            {
               // any checked
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**You may want to add (or use) an id on the container of these checkbox, to optimize selector speed.**

As for asp.net messing up client ids on controls, you can use

```
$('<%= MyControl.ClientID %>')
```

References:

- [Check if a checkbox is checked in a group of checkboxes in clientside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529319/check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-a-group-of-checkboxes-in-clientside)
- [How to validate a user chose at least one checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146234/asp-net-checkboxlist-how-to-validate-a-user-choose-at-least-one-checkbox)

Comment: It wasn't the ClientID that was messing up, it was simply that there is no object rendered for a radiobuttonlist, just a table of radiobuttons. But the method you gave for getting to the radiobuttons and checking the checked property works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no RadioButtonList in HTML so when you write `$find("<%= rbgAssetClass.ClientID %>");` you might not get what you expect. Examine the generated HTML to see which ID do you want to find or add a little more information about what you want to accomplish

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The RadioButtonList is rendered as a table with the same ID. Even though the name "MainContent_ctl00_rbgAssetClass" is correct, its not an object with a list of items. That's why I need Shekhar's answer to get to the inputs.