# select at least one checkbox out of 3 required field validator

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, jquery-validate, validation

I am trying to make my code to put required field validator so at least one checkbox will be selected out of three. 
This is my code:

```
<div class="left marginT5 marginR10">
 <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="option1" runat="server" class="styled" /> Choice1
 </div>
 <div class="left marginT5 marginR10">
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="option2" runat="server" class="styled" /> Choice2
 </div>
 <div class="left marginT5 marginR10">
 <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" value="option3" runat="server" class="styled" /> Choice3
 </div>
```

I know I can use checkboxlist but because of design issues I can only use single checkbox controls. 
Any idea how I can "force" the user to select at least one checkbox?
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: For the jQuery Validate plugin to function properly, your `input` elements must have a `name` attribute.  It works perfectly fine once you correct this error.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/q3yrd/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate a user choose at least one checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146234/how-to-validate-a-user-choose-at-least-one-checkbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and use a Custom Validator. This should get you started:

aspx

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
    EnableClientScript="true"
    ErrorMessage="Please choose at least one"
    ClientValidationFunction="ValidateRadioButtons">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

javascript/jQuery

```
function ValidateRadioButtons(source, args) {
  var options = $('.styled');
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].checked) {
      args.IsValid = true;
      return false;
    }
  }
  args.IsValid = false;
}
```

[Custom Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You should have server side validation too, just in case javascript is disabled.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to write a custom validation function.  He's already using the jQuery Validation plugin, but it's been broken by the missing `name` attributes on his `input` elements.

Comment: @Sparky I didn't see that tag when I read the question. The question talks about requiredvalidators not jQuery validate, so i guess that's why I went down the customvalidator route. I'll upvote your answer, to be honest I didn't know about the jQuery validate plugin.

Comment: I'm no ASP expert but I think `jQuery Validate` is included along with `unobtrusive validate` which is a plugin written by MS that is required for usage along with it.

Comment: @Sparky - This was helpful in the sense that sometimes, a page may have other asp.net validators and the code will be somewhat consistent.  I needed exactly this and it isn't obvious to me that the original code was making use of jQuery (EDIT - I see the tag now).

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this with `jquery-validate` so can I assume you're using the jQuery Validate plugin?  If so, you **must** use a `name` attribute on your `input` fields. And if all checkbox elements in the group have the same `name`, you will get the requested behavior ***by default***.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/q3yrd/**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk1" value="option1" runat="server" class="styled" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk2" value="option2" runat="server" class="styled" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk3" value="option3" runat="server" class="styled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since validators are "per-control", there's no one-whack out-of-box solution.  You will have to implement it on your own.  It should be easy enough, just not as easy as adding a required field validator...

The best approach is usually to validate both in javascript (client-side) and again server side on post-back, but depending on your application, either or both would work.